# Use generic base class in a collection of classes derived from generic

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary, abstract-class

I'm coming to C# from Java and I was unable to find out how to resolve the following issue:

I have a generic base class:

```
class MyBase<T>  where T : SomeAncestorOfTs
{ ... }
```

and then a few specialized classes (`A`,`B`,`C`...) derived from it, like:

```
class A : MyBase<SomeSpecificT> 
{ ... }
```

Now somewhere in my code I would like to create a `Dictionary` of various descendants of `MyBase`: something like `Dictionary<string,MyBase<>>`, but that's not working.

Is there a way in C# other than doing `Dictionary<String,Object>`?

In Java this would be easily achieved by doing `HashMap<String,MyBase<? extends SomeAncestorOfTs>>`.

**UPDATE**: `T` is supposed to have a common base class (`SomeAncestorOfT`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It cannot be done like that directly. My suggestion would be to add yet another, non-generic, base class:

```
class MyBase
{ ... }

class MyBase<T> : MyBase
{ ... }
```

And then make a dictionary of that base: `Dictionary<string,MyBase>`

Comment: I was just about to write the same thing (albeit with an interface rather than a class) +1.

Comment: I accepted your answer. But there's one thing I would say is not solvable: if the generic base class contains an abstract method that returns `T` (and hence cannot be in the non-generic primary base class), then I will never be able to call it (a call on the dictionary entry) without explicit casting.

Comment: @NumberFour Yeah that's true. At least for code in `MyBase`. Any code outside that class would know what `T` is anyway and could use `MyBase<T>`. So it's never gonna be perfect, but at least it won't be a problem for the rest of the code that's using those classes.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
public class SuperBase
{
}

internal class MyBase<T> : SuperBase
{
}


internal class A : MyBase<string>
{
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        Dictionary<string, SuperBase> _dict = new Dictionary<string, SuperBase>();

        _dict.Add("first", new MyBase<int>());
        _dict.Add("second", new MyBase<object>());
        _dict.Add("third", new MyBase<string>());
    }
}
```

This does not give a compilation error as it stands at least (although I can't guarantee that it won't produce other unforeseen headaches down the road).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **no** you cannot do this in C#. `MyBase<int>` and `MyBase<string>` do not share a base class other than `object`. Personally, I don't see what I would do with it even if it worked syntactically.

If all those instances share a behavior, let them all implement that interface and have a dictionary of those.

Comment: Those instances share a behavior (two methods), but one of the methods returns T.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine, does it help you?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, MyBase> dic = new Dictionary<string, MyBase>();
        A<int> test= new A<int>();

        dic.Add("test", test);
    }
}
class MyBase
{ }
class A<T> : MyBase
{}
```

Comment: Try adding an instance of `A` to that dictionary.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm sorry, I'll give it some more thought and update it again.

Comment: Hehe. I'm pretty sure that won't compile.

Comment: Now it does compile, but I'm unsure it behaves the way the asker wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyBase<T>
{ ... }

class A : MyBase<SomeSpecificT> 
{ ... }
```

if you don't want to use Object, you can use dynamic.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<String, MyBase<dynamic>>();
```

Comment: That's not what `dynamic` is meant for.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out, i won't delete the post so that others can know that dynamic shouldn't be used